# Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route` in Route. Issue with props?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm having some issues getting my main `App` component to render when using React-Router. Below is my `index.js` code:

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

// React router goodies
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';    //All pieces of the router object

const App = require('./components/App.jsx');
const SingleMatchup = require('./components/SingleMatchup.jsx');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <Route path='/teams' component={SingleMatchup}>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And here is the App component I am trying to render:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import Matchups from './Matchups.jsx';
import {Jumbotron} from 'react-bootstrap';
import NavBar from './NavBar.jsx';
import axios from 'axios';
import gameLogs from '../gameLogs.js'

export default class App extends React.Component {


  componentDidMount() {
    for(var team in gameLogs) {
      let teamToUpdate = team
      axios.post('/stats', {team: teamToUpdate})
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
        <div>
        <NavBar />
         <Jumbotron>
          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
          <p>This is a simple hero unit</p>
        </Jumbotron>
        <Matchups />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if the problem has something to do with passing props down, or if their is some issue with components rendering other components? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which version of router u r using ??

Comment: I was using 4.0.0, but I downgraded to 3.0.0 because version 4 was giving me issues.

Comment: in version3 this code will work properly, for 4 you need to do changes

Comment: No, in fact there were additional errors in version 3

Comment: didn't get the solution? can you mention that errors will try to help you.

Comment: The only errors I'm getting are the one I posted in the title, "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route`' and ' Uncaught Error: The root route must render a single element'